# NSIS roll-back installer if ExecWait command gets a specific return code

Tags: nsis

I'm currently using the following script to install drivers along with my application:

```
!macro customInstall
  ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\resources\DPInst.exe" /sw'
!macroend
```

However, if `DPInst` returns `>= 0x80010000`, this means one or more of the driver installs has failed so I need to roll-back the installation and quit. Any idea how I would do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExecWait can store the process exit code in the 2nd parameter. Not much you can do to roll it back, it is best just to do it early in the install phase:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Section
SetOutPath "$instdir\resources"
File "whatever\DPInst.exe"
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\resources\DPInst.exe" /sw' $0
${If} $0 U>= 0x80010000
  Delete "$INSTDIR\resources\DPInst.exe"
  RMDir $instdir\resources
  RMDir $instdir
  MessageBox mb_iconstop "Error blah blah"
  Abort
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: This works, but as there is no easy way to roll back with my setup, I decided to parse the output of `PnPUtil` within the app to check if the drivers are installed and re-prompt for driver installation if they're missing.